# Largest permutation groups without "non-mixing" subgroups

Tags: nt.number-theory, gr.group-theory, permutation-groups, collatz-conjecture

We say that a subgroup of ${\rm Sym}(\mathbb{N})$ has *sparse orbit representatives*
if it has infinitely many orbits on $\mathbb{N}$, but the set of smallest orbit
representatives has natural density 0 (and in particular its natural density exists).

Which are the with respect to inclusion largest subgroups of ${\rm Sym}(\mathbb{N})$
which do not have finitely generated subgroups with sparse orbit representatives?

Comment: What's the relation with the Collatz conjecture ?

Comment: @SébastienPalcoux: Let $G$ be the group mentioned under "Ad 2" in http://mathoverflow.net/questions/112527/,
and let $H$ be the permutation group induced by $G$ on $\mathbb{N}$.
If $H$ is a subgroup of one of the groups this question asks for, then the Collatz graph
has only finitely many connected components. -- That said, the question is much more
general, and a sufficiently explicit answer could be of interest well beyond the
Collatz conjecture.